Is the slash still required in HTML link tags?
I've noticed the official MDN website uses this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel#alternate
<link
  rel="alternate"
  href="/fr/pdf"
  hreflang="fr"
  type="application/pdf"
  title="French PDF" />

However, when I check the code with the W3C validator, it says:

Trailing slash on void elements has no effect and interacts badly
with unquoted attribute values.

If I remove the slash, then I no longer receive the info message:
<link
  rel="alternate"
  href="/fr/pdf"
  hreflang="fr"
  type="application/pdf"
  title="French PDF">


That slash has never been required. The slash has never been specified as having any meaning or value in any HTML standard since the beginning of HTML. If anything, it can cause issues you do not want.
